# Relationship one-To-Many return empty set

Tags: java, spring

here is my Post class which has relationship as OneToMany

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Integer postId;

    @Column(name = "post_name")
    private String postName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "postId=" + postId +
                ", postName='" + postName + '\'' +
                ", comments=" + comments +
                '}';
    }

    public Integer getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    public void setPostId(Integer postId) {
        this.postId = postId;
    }

    public String getPostName() {
        return postName;
    }

    public void setPostName(String postName) {
        this.postName = postName;
    }

    public Set<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

and related to each Post i have multiple comments as
/*
i
want
result 
as post 
and 
related it's comments

*/

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer commentId;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id",referencedColumnName = "post_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private Post post;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Comment{" +
                "commentId=" + commentId +
                ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
                ", post=" + post +
                '}';
    }

    public Integer getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }

    public void setCommentId(Integer commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
    }
}
```

these are the repositories

```
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment,Integer> {
    List<Comment> findAllByPostPostId(Integer postId);
}


public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post,Integer> {
}
```

these are my Rest mapping

```
@Autowired
private PostRepository postRepository;

@Autowired
private CommentRepository commentRepository;

@RequestMapping(value= "/post" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addPost(@RequestBody Post post){
        System.out.println("addPost: " +post);
        postRepository.save(post);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/comment/{postId}" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addComment(@RequestBody Comment comment,@PathVariable Integer postId){

        Post post = postRepository.findOne(postId);
        comment.setPost(post);

        System.out.println("addComment: " +comment);
        commentRepository.save(comment);
    }
```

output:

//addComment: Comment{commentId=null, comment='modi', post=Post{postId=1, postName='politics', comments=[]}}

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post/{postId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getComments(@PathVariable Integer postId){
        Post post = postRepository.findOne(postId);
        System.out.println(post);
    }
```

and i am trying to print Post with it's all comment but comment Set returns null

it return response as:

addPost: Post{postId=null, postName='politics', comments=[]}

Post{postId=1, postName='politics', comments=[]}

Comment: Because it is lazy.`fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. change it to `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: i tried but it's still return me empty

Comment: What is the reference column in both tables ?

Comment: as you can see : post_id

Comment: Do you have data in both tables ? and could you please add code related to **postRepository.findOne(postId)** ?

Comment: could you please remove the toString method from comment table ? because of this your system must throw StackOverflow exception and that might be an issue

Comment: what is HQL or SQL query for **findAllByPostPostId** this call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forbid updating Post in Comment entity. Remove insertable and updatable attributes

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id",referencedColumnName = "post_id")
    private Post post;
}
```

Then break circular references in toString() method to avoid StackOverflowException.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Comment{" +
            "commentId=" + commentId +
            ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
            // ", post=" + post +
            '}';
}
```

**I also recommend not to use eager fetching and to read how to make bi-directional association.**

Comment: Removing insertable and updatable attributes works for me why is it so?

Comment: @NavinGelot Because when you do comment.setPost(post); in the Controller and post is not updatable it is not stored in DB.

Answer (score 0):

as your code display it is `lazy`. if you want to get it by fetching `post` entity so change it to `eager`.

also you should correct `mappedBy` to `post`.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: it's not working i tried as per answer but my in my data post_id returns NULL

mysql> select * from comment;
+----+---------+---------+
| id | comment | post_id |
+----+---------+---------+

|  1 | amit    |    NULL |

|  2 | modi    |    NULL 
|
+----+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from post;

+---------+-----------+
| post_id | post_name |
+---------+-----------+

|       1 | politics  |

+---------+-----------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: of course it doesn't work due to relations were wrong before. rerun your project and insert new data(post and comments) then test it again.

Comment: as you text me, i have made changes as you can see edited code and REST mapping and at last shown output on console  but still it stores null in database

Comment: please display how insert `comment` into db?

Comment: as you can see second REST mapping is a code and and at last i printed output of all three

Answer (score 0):

You should not use toString method in both table creating a cyclic call

try removing the toString() from Comment class

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer commentId;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id" , referencedColumnName = "post_id", insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private Post post;


    public Integer getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }

    public void setCommentId(Integer commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Table() annotation is only required only if i want to change my table name and as you can see Comment becomes comment by default so it is not necessary but still i tried and it's not working